# How do I loop through a set of items in a databound Silverlight control such as the ListBox?

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight ListBox that has it's ItemsSource set. From the C# code behind I want to loop through each ListBox item and change the value of the text and access controls that are in the ListBox ItemTemplate. How would I do that?

Comment: Was the solution listed helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListBox controls in silverlight are bound to an ienumerable type, so that if any value in the ListBox changes, the underlying data is changed and vice versa depending on what type of binding you require.  To effectively iterate the items you'll want to iterate through the enumerable object you've bound to.

You can get to the collection by accessing the ListBox.ItemsSource property and change the text of appropriate items, perform LINQqueries etc.  If you have bound the controls correctly, saving the collection should update the list.

Hope this helps!